# Angular ng-options value DOES NOT update when scope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having problems creating a select option dropdown using ng-options.

Scope structure

```
vm.filters = {
    perPage: 10, 
    settings: {
      perPage: {
        intervals: [
          {
            label: 'All',
            value: null
          }, {
            label: 10,
            value: 10
          }, {
            label: 25,
            value: 25
          }, {
            label: 50,
            value: 50
          }, {
            label: 100,
            value: 100
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

Dom Element (angular generates the `option` tags)

```
<select name="selectPerPage" data-ng-model="vm.filters.perPage" data-ng-options="interval.value as interval.label for interval in vm.filters.settings.perPage.intervals">
    <option label="All" value="object:null">All</option>
    <option label="10" value="number:10" selected="selected">10</option>
    <option label="25" value="number:25">25</option>
    <option label="50" value="number:50">50</option>
    <option label="100" value="number:100">100</option>
</select>
```

When I change the value property of the first object in the intervals array from `null` to an actual number, scope for the `option` elements do not update. Why? How can I get it to update? It's almost like `ng-model` isn't referencing when scope updates.

Comment: where is `filters.settings`?

Comment: @tanmay Sorry left out a prop, see above.

Comment: why have 2 perpage

Comment: @JoshSpears instead of `interval.value as interval.label` use `interval as interval.label` with `ng-model="something"`and have an `ng-change` to set `filters.perPage = something.value` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ng-options`, you should not hard-coded options as you did in your select. You can only hard one (generally a null value).

```
<select ng-model="vm.filters.perPage" 
        ng-options="interval.value as interval.label for interval in vm.filters.settings.perPage.intervals">
    <option label="All" value="">All</option>
</select>
```

I don't know what type `interval.value` is (array, object, string?), but it should be saved in `vm.filters.perPage` (supposing vm.filters exists).

Comment: I think OP hasn't hardcoded it.. he copied HTML from browser devtools and that's why it has `<option>`s

Comment: Yea I just copied the option tags for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `ng-repeat`, this will update the options dynamically. But unfortunately if the first element is selected when you update the data, the `ng-change` event won't be fired which means the value binded with `ng-model` won't be updated and you have to update it manually.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.filters = {
      perPage: {
        intervals: [{
          label: 'All',
          value: null
        }, {
          label: 10,
          value: 10
        }, {
          label: 25,
          value: 25
        }, {
          label: 50,
          value: 50
        }, {
          label: 100,
          value: 100
        }]
      }
    };
    $scope.update = function() {
      $scope.filters.perPage.intervals[0].value = 1000;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <!--<select name="selectPerPage" data-ng-model="perPage" data-ng-options="interval.value as interval.label for interval in filters.perPage.intervals"> -->
  <select name="selectPerPage" data-ng-model="perPage">
    <option ng-repeat="interval in filters.perPage.intervals" value="{{interval.value}}">{{interval.label}}</option>
  </select>
{{perPage}}
<button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
</div>
```